# Jsoup adds userAgent and still reports an error,how should I end it?

Tags: jsoup, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
      String url = "https://www.ozon.ru";
        Connection connect = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0");
        Document document = connect.get();
        System.out.println(document.html());
```

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=[https://www.ozon.ru]

    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:912)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:851)
```

This website can be accessed normally with Google Chrome, but when accessed with httpclient or jsoup, error 403 is reported. How should I solve it?